# Is there a short hand command to write derivatives?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, shorthands

Every time I want to write an (ordinary) derivative I have to use `frac`, like this:

```
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 \omega}{\mathrm{d}\theta^2}
```

Or using `\partial` for partial derivatives.

Is there a package or a command that takes, for instance, (Ordinary or Partial, Power of derivative, variables) and outputs the formatted expression?

Comment: one is `physics` for other i temporary don't remember a name :-(

Comment: Certainly you can define abbreviations, but I would recommend not doing this since you may want to share your TeX code with others. Then you probably don't want to mess with their shortcuts, and the others may not be too excited about yours either. Use shortcuts in your editor instead.

Comment: `\partial`, for example.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use  the [`esdiff`](https://ctan.org/pkg/esdiff?lang=en) package, which  has  handy macros for derivatives and partial derivatives, taking care of indices. Here is a demo;

```
\documentclass{article}%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[thinc]{esdiff}

 \begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
     \diff{f}{x} &\qquad \diff*[4]{g}{t}{t = 1} \\[2ex]
     \diffp{f}{x} &\qquad\diffp{g}{tu}& & \qquad & \diffp*{g}{{t^2}{u^3}}{(0,0)}
 \end{alignat*}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +5 for my friend. I still have the account stuck on Mathematics. Could you please take a look at my combinatorial question and publish it, please?

Comment: @ Sebastiano: Do you mean, publish it  in my name, or edit yours? Or if you want, I know a combinatorial proof for your question?

Comment: Edit my question and after you give me a combinatorial proof for your question. The answers are blocked

Comment: @Sebastiano: I've modified your question (without changing its title) to put it in a more general context. Please see if it's OK. I'm not sure it will be enough to re-open it, though.

Comment: Is there any option in `esdiff` to write the simple differential (to be used at the end of an integration) ?

Comment: @ParthaD.: No there is n't. But you may take a look at the `diffcoeff` package, which has a `\dl` command and is  quite customisable through a set of options, and a config file if you want.

Answer (score 35):

Oh, you mean not symbol, but operator. There is `physics`, as stated by @Zarko.

- `\differential` produces the variants of `d`: `\dd x`
- `\derivative` yields the $df/dx$ in variants: `\dv{x}`, `\dv{f}{x}`
- `\partialderivative` produces the partial symbol in derivaties a la carte, similar to `\dv`, use `\pdv x`, etc.
- `\variation` and `\functionalderivative` are also there, e.g. `\fdv{F}{g}`.

It's all in the documentation on pages 5-6, say `texdoc physics` for the pdf.

---

Screenshot from the document.

[image]

Answer (score 20):

There is also another important and easy package to write
ordinary derivate and partial derivatives named [`derivative`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/derivative/derivative.pdf). I have added only some simple examples how to use this package where the `d` ("classical derivate") is written in roman.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{derivative}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\[\odv{f(x)}{x}, \qquad \odv[n]{f(x)}{x}, \qquad \pdv[\alpha,b,c]{f}{x,y,z}\]
\[\pdv{f}{x,y}, \qquad \odv{e^{\tan(x)}}{x}, \qquad \odv{\cos t}{t}_{t=0}^{}\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

One option is to use `\newcommand`. Add the following lines to the preamble of your document

```
\newcommand{\pd}[2]{\frac{\partial{#1}}{\partial{#2}}}
\newcommand{\pdd}[2]{\frac{\partial^2{#1}}{\partial{#2}^2}}
```

These can be used within the document as follows

```
\pd u t = \pdd u x
```

Result:

[image]

Of course, `\pd{u}{x}` is preferable aesthetically and often the only correct syntax, but I am mainly trying to illustrate a minimal method to print the derivatives.

EDIT: A command for mixed derivatives and a generalization of the double derivative command to include multiple derivatives

```
\newcommand{\pdd}[3]{\frac{\partial^#1{#2}}{\partial{#3}^#1}}
\newcommand{\pdm}[6]{\frac{\partial^#1{#2}}{\partial{#4}^#3 \partial{#6}^#5}}
```

Then

```
\pd y t = \pdd 4 y t + \pdm 5y 2x 3t
```

gives

[image]

Answer (score 6):

There is also another package ([`commath`](https://ctan.org/pkg/commath?lang=en)) that provides, along with many other commands for general mathematical typesetting, a few ways to print derivatives via `\od`, `\pd` or `\md`. These commands automatically choose the dimensions for text or display style. You can also use `\tod`, `\tpd` or `\tmd` for text style derivatives and their relative `\dod`, `\dpd` and `\dmd` versions.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{commath,amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation*}
    \od{f}{x},\qquad\pd{f}{x},\qquad\pd[2]{f}{x}
  \end{equation*}
  \begin{equation*}
    \od[2]{f}{x},\qquad\md{f}{4}{x}{3}{y}{ }
  \end{equation*}
  \begin{equation*}
    \tod{f}{x},\qquad\tpd[2]{f}{x},\qquad\tmd{f}{4}{x}{3}{y}{ }
  \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: That's very good. I didn't know this package. In fact, it's a little old.

Answer (score 4):

Another package datated December 28, 2019 is `diffcoeff` to write the differential coefficients. Here there is some examples:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{diffcoeff,amssymb}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \diffp L{q_k}-\diff*{\diffp L{\dot{q}_k}[]}t = 0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \diffp {F(x,y)}x[(1,-4)]
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \diffp*{\diff{x^\mu}{y}}{x^\lambda}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There is not only the symbol of partial but also the classical derivates `d/dx`.

Answer (score 2):

### For macOS users of iWork

The solution pointed out by @pulkit (define a new command) is your only choice if you are typesetting in the iWork office suite.

These are the commands he proposed:

```
\newcommand{\pd}[2]{\frac{\partial{#1}}{\partial{#2}}}
\newcommand{\pdd}[2]{\frac{\partial^2{#1}}{\partial{#2}^2}}
```

In case you don't know, you can use LaTeX and MathML in all iWork apps ([see here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202501)).
Go to `Insert` > `Equation...` or press <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>.

However, in iWork you cannot import a package, but you are allowed to define new commands.